# How can model in Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.ID) become Student when @model is IEnumerable<Student>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

## `Details.cshtml`

When we have `@model Student` in `Details.cshtml`, we can invoke `Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.ID)` because `model` is a `Student`.

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student
<h2>Details</h2>
<dl >
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
    </dt>          
</dl>
```

## `Index.cshtml`

I am confused with the case in which we have `@model IEnumerable<Student>` in `Index.cshtml` and we can also invoke `Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.ID)`, even though `model` is no longer a `Student` but `IEnumerable<Student>`.

```
@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>

<h2>Index</h2>

<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
            </th>           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)
                </td>                
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Have you done this in code ? Does your code compile and Run ? The second one is using `foreach` so it should work, but the first part has no `foreach` so it should not compile.

Comment: @user3185569: Yes. It works. `Html.DisplayFor` is not the point in question, but `Html.DisplayNameFor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of one of the overloads from the DisplayNameFor Method listed in this article. This automaticly calls the inner model.

[DisplayNameFor for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7BSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7B%60%600%7D%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D%29)

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature for the method that you're using:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>
                (this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html, 
                                Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
```

So when you pass a List as a model, the overload is called and this overload has an expression that operates on the type `TModel` which is the type of the items of the sequence `IEnumerable<TModel>`

For the first case, this method overload is the one called since the model is not a sequence:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>
                 (this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
                  Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
```

Comment: @SingleFighter Typo fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the first correct answer must be accepted for the sake of fairness.